# How to append two tables sharing some columns of their data schema in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, append

I have table A in **BIGQUERY**:

| prod_Id | country | brand | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | FR | ABCE | 20 |
| 1234 | BE | ASCT | 30 |

I have a table B in **BIGQUERY**:

| prod_Id | country | brand | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 987 | DE | UTCE | 1 | 11 |
| 8561 | IT | ASCT | 3 | 33 |

I would like to append them and have as outcomes in **BIGQUERY**: :

| prod_Id | country | brand | volume | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | FR | ABCE | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 1234 | BE | ASCT | 30 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | DE | UTCE | NULL | 1 | 11 |
| 8561 | IT | ASCT | NULL | 3 | 33 |

Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT prod_id, 
       country, 
       brand, 
       volume, 
       NULL AS quantity, 
       NULL AS price 
FROM   tablea 
UNION ALL 
SELECT prod_id, 
       country, 
       brand, 
       NULL AS volume, 
       quantity, 
       price 
FROM   tableb
```